# Catching a missing operand or operator in stack while converting to postfix from infix

Tags: c, stack, postfix-notation, infix-notation

I have been attempting to figure out how to be able to catch a missing operand or operator while converting from infix to postfix.

e.g.)

```
Tall = Y
```

would print out

```
Tall Y =
```

I thought about implementing a local variable to count the number of operators and operands and have it set to

```
if(Operators + 1 < Operands )
   return errexitMissing Operator);
if(Operators + 1 > Operands )
   return errexit(Missing Operand);
```

So far the code seemed to work but then I could not figure out how to be able to deal with parenthesis

e.g)

```
(Tall = ) Y
```

That text should return an error since there is no operand after the parenthesis but instead returns it like such

```
Tall Y =
```

I'm at a loss at the moment and can't seem how to deal with the parenthesis :/

Answer (score 0):

One way to extend your approach is to write a function that counts the number of operators and operands inside a given subexpression, where a subexpression is enclosed in parentheses. The easiest way to do this is with a recursive descent parser (handles nesting elegantly). That said, I am not convinced that counting operators and operands will actually work in the general case. You will probably need to consider many more cases.

That is to say, you need to verify the innermost parenthesized subexpression first (depth first recursion), and then you need to evaluate it and use it as part of the enclosing subexpression to verify that one, so on, until you have parsed the entire expression.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to handle the parentheses problem is to keep track of whether the last token you processed was an operator or an operand. An open paren, `(`, can only occur at the beginning of the line, or after an operator. A close paren, `)`, can only occur after an operand.

If you keep track of the last token, then when you encounter the close paren in `(Tail = ) Y`, you know there's an error because the `)` came after an operator.

You can extend that to the general case and keep track of whether you're expecting an operand or an operator next. You know, for example, that you can't have two operands in a row. That is, if the infix expression is `A B + C`, you know when you encounter `B` that the expression is invalid.

Similarly, you don't normally have multiple operators in a row, although unary operators are a notable exception: `A + - B` is perfectly valid.

In general, infix-to-postfix conversion problems assume that the infix expression is valid. If you need the ability to catch errors, you need to add some syntax checking to enforce the rules of infix expressions.